# Permutation of multiple categorical columns

Tags: python, r, permutation

I am trying to built a database based on a table with 5 categorical columns (Business, Product Type, Vendor, Region and Country) and as a measure sales.

The idea is to aggregate the sales amount by all permutation of the 5 categorical columns (Total of 120 different aggregations).

Table example:

| Cat A | Cat B | Cat C | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | Spain | Mercadona | 100 |
| Orange | UK | Tesco | 100 |
| Strawberry | Ireland | Mercadona | 100 |
| Orange | Germany | Mercadona | 100 |
| Orange | Spain | Fnac | 100 |
| Strawberry | Germany | Saturn | 100 |
| Orange | Turkey | CorteIngles | 100 |
| Blueberry | France | Fnac | 100 |

Feel free to use the table as bases I can then extrapolate to the database.

Overall my objective with the permutation is to then "quickly" identify where the biggest YoY variances come from and hopefully "automate" some comments/insights on the data based on a correct sequence of A,B,C or D to deep dive.

I have no language preference feel free to use R or Python.
I do expect the size of the database greatly increase.

thanks for your time!
kind regards,
Kylian

Comment: are you looking to aggregate the sales per unique combination of values across the categorical columns? 
I found this as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862105/count-unique-combinations-of-values

Comment: Yes. I need the aggregation of sales for each permutation. Example on record would be Orange (no other category) and 500. The link provided i've check and  works for eliminating duplicates the data i have each row is a unique record.

Comment: I've found the same question already solved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213656/how-to-get-various-combinations-of-categories-in-a-categorical-variable-and-at-t

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get various combinations of categories in a categorical variable and at the same time aggregate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213656/how-to-get-various-combinations-of-categories-in-a-categorical-variable-and-at-t)